# Pull data from multiple worksheets using Excel as database

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

It would be really helpful if you advise me on how to query and pull data from multiple excel worksheets using ADODB record set. Below is my VBA script, it's throwing me "Type Mismatch Error".

VBA Code:

```
Dim sSQLQry As String
Dim conn As New ADODB.connection
Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim DBpath As String
Dim sconnect As String

Private Sub Generate_Testcase_Click()
DBpath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBpath & ";HDR=Yes';"
conn.Open sconnect

sSQLQry = "SELECT TOP 1 [Sheet1$].EMPLOYEEID FROM [Sheet1$] INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] ON [Sheet1$].EMPLOYEEID =[Sheet2$].PPTID AND [Sheet2$].UNION_CD =[Sheet1$].UNID"

mrs.Open sSQLQry, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
MsgBox mrs.Fields(0) & " , " & mrs.Fields(1)
mrs.Close
conn.Close
End Sub
```

Also I tried with below query as well, but still same errror.

```
sSQLQry = "SELECT TOP 1 [Sheet1$].EMPLOYEEID FROM [Sheet1$], [Sheet2$] WHERE [Sheet1$].EMPLOYEEID =[Sheet2$].PPTID AND [Sheet2$].UNION_CD =[Sheet1$].UNID"
```

Please help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the issue, both the columns [Sheet1$].EMPLOYEEID and [Sheet2$].PPTID are in a different format. The issue was fixed once I changed both columns to the same format.